# How to modify the shortcut so that a certain program runs with high priority?

Tags: priority

This says I got to do something like

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89548-set-cpu-process-priority-applications-windows-10-a.html

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" /AboveNormal "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"
```

How does the command really work? I know /c means run this. Then empty quote? Empty parameter?

There isn't really easier way to do this? Like option boxes or something?

According to this

https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

It effectively run program with title window "". But then it puts the path of the program in the command section of "start" parameter. I am getting confused. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am getting confused. Is this correct?

Yes. The title parameter is required (but may be empty) if the remainder of the command line contains something in double `"`s.

In your case, if you **don't** include`""` the `cmd` shell will use `"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"` as the window **title** and there will be no `command` to run.

You can, however, fill in the empty title with **your own text**. For example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "My super duper title" /AboveNormal "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"
```

This is (partially) explained in the [link](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) you quoted:

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Source: [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)