# Why this shortcut doesn't run my game in high priority?

Tags: windows-10

I have a short cut to run skyrim special edition automatically in high priority

I followed the instruction here [How to modify the shortcut so that a certain program runs with high priority?](https://superuser.com/questions/1592414/how-to-modify-the-shortcut-so-that-a-certain-program-runs-with-high-priority)

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" /High "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\skse64_loader.exe"
```

However, when I go to task manager and check it's obvious that my program runs in normal mode and I have to manually turn that into high priority mode.

What went wrong?

Oh ya, skse64_loader is loading another program skyrim, and that's probably the issue. So what should I do? I want to run Skyrim in high priority through that shortcut.

Some articles talk about it

http://tesalliance.org/forums/index.php?/topic/4653-running-skyrim-in-high-priority-the-easy-way/

However, many skyrim players, including me, uses SKSE and that means we got to run SKSE loader.

I wonder if there is a way out. Also this is skyrim special edition and not skyrim.

Comment: A different priority class doesn’t make the program run faster or slower anyway—unless some _other_ program is also using substantial amounts of CPU time.

Comment: If skse64_loader starts another program, you need to set the priority of that program. Check if the game is indeed another program.

Comment: Yes it's another program. However, that other program can only be loaded from skse64_loader. It's the way it works. I wonder if there is a bat file. Basically, run skse64_loader and then turn existing process to high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you don't need to start the game in High Priority.  You just want it to be in high priority.

Make a batch file that does this:

> @Echo Off
>
> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" /High "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\skse64_loader.exe"
>
> ping 127.0.0.1 -n 36 > nul
>
> wmic process where name="skyrim.exe" call setpriority "128"

That works as long as you start Skyrim within about 35 seconds.  If you may regularly need more time, you can increase that number.

credit: https://winaero.com/change-process-priority-windows-10/

Comment: I'm guessing SkyRim's executable is skyrim.exe.  You can use Task Manager, or run TaskList.exe from a command line, to help determine the process names.

Comment: skyrim se but good enough. I know how to do it now

Answer (score 0):

I selected @Toogam answer as the answer. I just want to add that the one actually works for me is to create this bat file in the same directory of Skyrim

```
skse64_loader.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 36 > nul
wmic process where name="SkyrimSE.exe" call setpriority "128"
```

This one work as expected.